# How to create PHP cache function?

Tags: php, xml, caching

I have the following code:

```
<?php

$items = simplexml_load_file("http://foo.xml");

foreach ($items->bar->baz as $item) {
echo $item;
}
?>
```

I want to cache the xml file, so I was told to use:

```
$cacheName = "foo.xml.cache";

// generate the cache version if it doesn't exist or it's too old!
$ageInSeconds = 24 * 60 * 60; // one day

if (!file_exists($cacheName) || filemtime($cacheName) > time() + $ageInSeconds)
{ 
$contents = file_get_contents("http://foo.xml");
    file_put_contents($cacheName, $contents);
}

$dom = simplexml_load_file($cacheName);
```

I tried creating a function called to call right before the foreach loop.  How can I do this?  Thank you!

Comment: Could you be clearer in the problem you're facing? What fails exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I think this expression is backwards:

```
filemtime($cacheName) > time() + $ageInSeconds
```

I think it should be

```
filemtime($cacheName) + $ageInSeconds < time()
```

or, equivalently:

```
filemtime($cacheName) < time() - $ageInSeconds
```